# Vector fields on quasi-spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

In 1962, Adams proved that there do not exist $\rho(n)$ linearly independent vector fields on the sphere $S^{n-1}$, where $\rho(n)$ is the Hurwitz-Radon number. I wonder if this is still true in the case of quasi-sphere (a sphere in the pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n_{\nu}$ of index $\nu$).

Comment: @ArunDebray these questions are not smooth deformation retract invariants. $\mathbf{R}^3-\{0\}$ is parallelizable but is SDR to the 2-sphere...

Comment: @YCor Are not they just diffeomorphic to some $\mathbb R^i\times S^j$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე why do you ask me? rather ask the OP. I mentioned that there are trivial counterexamples, it's enough for me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks to @მამუკაჯიბლაძე. It is a better question, is there a similar bound for vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^{\nu}\times S^{m-1}$.